# Visual studio vb.net project including XML files

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm having some difficulty including XML files within my project. I have a simple windows forms application in VB, and part of this uses info from an included XML document. This file is in the solution explorer, and running the project from within Visual Studio, appears to work fine. The properties of the XML document are set to 'content' and 'always copy', but when I publish, the resultant program fails as it can't find the XML! I'm sure I'm missing something basic, any ideas?

Thanks

Edit

The code that loads the xml is

```
lbEngineers.Items.Clear()
    Dim xm As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    Dim list As String = "/Engineers/Engineer/Name"
    xm.Load("engineers.xml")
    Dim Xn As XmlNodeList = xm.SelectNodes(list)

    For Each xNode As XmlNode In Xn
        lbEngineers.Items.Add(xNode.InnerText)

    Next
```

I've temporarily got round it by directly copying the XML file and changing the path to

`xm.Load("C:\Rams Software\engineers.xml")`

but this feels clunky and wrong!

I've not used `my.resources`, I though this was more for image files and the like?

Comment: Show the code that reads the XML file.

Comment: Are you using `My.Resources`? If not, consider doing so rather than putting it into the project directory and including it into the project.